# Mid-Autumn Festival Dice Game (20-sided dice)

Tags: probability, statistics

I recently came across an improved Mid-Autumn Dice Game Problem wherein instead of six sides of a dice there a twenty sides (thus 20-sided dice).

In the problem, the same rule applies for the prizes, there are six 20-sided dice. Here are the prize rules:

- **First prize** - six of a kind (A, A, A, A, A, A) or five of a kind (A, A, A, A, A, ?) or four 4s
- **Second prize** - straight (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) or two triples (A, A, A, B, B, B)
- **Third prize** - three 4s
- **Fourth prize** - four of a kind (A, A, A, A, ?, ?) or four 3s and two 4s
- **Fifth prize** - two 4s
- **Sixth prize** - one 4

The goal is to solve the probability of each prizes. Here are my answers:

**First Prize**
$ 1 * \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^5 \tag{1a}$

Where $1$ is the first die which could be any of the 20 faces, and $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^5$ which should match the first.

$ 1 * \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4 * \big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big) * 6\tag{1b}$

Where $1$ is the first die which could be any of the 20 faces, $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4$ are the 4 dice which should match the first, $\big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)$ is the last die which should be different, and $6$ is the number of permutations.

$ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4 * \big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)^2 * \frac{6!}{4!2!} \tag{1c}$

Where $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4$ are four dice which must show 4, $\big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)^2$ are the last two dice which could be any other face, and $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$ is the number of permutations.

We then combine them all for the first prize:

$ \Big[ 1 * \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^5 \Big] + \Big[1 * \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4 * \big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big) * 6 \Big] + \Big[ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4 * \big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)^2 * \frac{6!}{4!2!} \Big] \tag{1}$

**Second Prize**
$ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6 * 6!\tag{2a} $

Where $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6$ are each faces (1-6) which should appear once and $6!$ is the number of permutations.

$ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6 * \binom{6}{2} * \frac{6!}{3!3!} \tag{2b}$

Where $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6$ is only one option for each die in AAABBB sequence, $\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of AB combinations, and $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ is the number of permutations.

We then combine them all for the second prize:

$ \Big[ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6 * 6! \Big] + \Big[ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^6 * \binom{6}{2} * \frac{6!}{3!3!} \Big] \tag{2}$

**Third Prize**
$ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^3 * \frac{5^3-5}{20^3} * \frac{6!}{3!3!} \tag{3}$

Where $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^3$ are the three 4s, $\frac{5^3-5}{20^3}$ is other dice which can be any face but subtract the triples (111, 222, etc), and $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ is the number of permutations.

**Fourth Prize**
$ 5 * \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4 * \big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)^2 * \frac{6!}{4!2!}\tag{4}$

Where $5$ is five possible kinds, $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^4$ is the next three dice which should match the first die, $\big(\frac{5}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{7}{20} + \dots + \frac{19}{20}\big)^2$ are the last two dies which should not match the first, and $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$ is the number of permutations.

**Fifth Prize**
$ \big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^2 * \frac{5^4-5}{20^4} * \frac{6!}{4!2!}\tag{5}$

Where $\big(\frac{1}{20}\big)^2$ is the two 4s, $\frac{5^4-5}{20^4}$ are other four dice which could be any other face, but we subtract 4-of-a-kinds, and $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$ is the number of permutations.

**Sixth Prize**
$ \frac{1}{20} * \frac{5^5-5-100-5!}{20^5} * 6 \tag{6}$

Where $\frac{1}{20}$ is the one 4 die, $\frac{5^5-5-100-5!}{20^5}$ are other dice which could be any other face but we subtract 5-of-a-kinds ($5$), 4-of-a-kind ($100$), and straights ($5!$).

Can you check if this is correct as well as to help clarify solutions to the other prize probabilities? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't six of one kind be $({1\over 20})^5$?  There are $20$ sides, not $6$, so the denominator should be $20$.  If you agree, why don't you correct this error (in _all_ your answers) and we can check them again?

Comment: @antkam, I just revised the description.

Comment: If you want "a die shows a different result than <some other die>", the prob is ${19\over 20}$.  There is no need to add ${5\over 20} + {6 \over 20} + \cdots + {19 \over 20}$.  (Indeed the sum $> 1$ so it cannot be a probability any more.)  This error is in your answers for (1b), (1c), (4)...

Comment: Also, you continue to confuse $20$ (no. of faces) with $6$ (no. of dice), e.g. in (2) it should be ${20 \choose 2}$ instead of ${6 \choose 2}$.  I have a suggestion: Maybe try writing the formulas using $F$ and $D$ for no. of faces & no. of dice?  Perhaps that will reduce the confusion, i.e., it might be more obvious that in (2) when choosing A and B that it should be ${F \choose 2}$ and not ${D \choose 2}$.

Comment: I still think it would be more helpful to you to try to work this out yourself.  Would you be interested in correcting your errors again, and I will check again later?  (BTW, I just noticed in (3), the $5^3 - 5$ should be $(F-1)^3 - (F-1) = 19^3 - 19$, i.e. same error as previous comment.)

Comment: (off topic) I am original from Hong Kong (where mid-Autumn is a big festival) but have never heard of this dice game.  What is its name (Chinese or English or any other native language)?  Which country / region is it from?

Comment: @antkam The game is called [Bo Bing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo_Bing_(game)) and the game dates back to the 1600s. Thanks for the help, BTW.